# Multiple jQuery slideshow instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I've created a very simple jQuery slideshow but am running into issues when it comes to having two of them on the page. I thought that by defining all of the variables locally the issue would be resolved, however I can't seem to find the solution.

Right now the second instance works normally but the first does not. It either activates the second, or does nothing at all.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3pkujpur/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="navigator">
        <a class="prev">Prev</a>
        <a class="next">Next</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="slider">
        <li class="active">
            <h2>Slider 1 Slide 1</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Slider 1 Slide 2</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Slider 1 Slide 3</h2>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="navigator">
        <a class="prev">Prev</a>
        <a class="next">Next</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="slider">
        <li class="active">
            <h2>Slider 2 Slide 1</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Slider 2 Slide 2</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Slider 2 Slide 3</h2>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.slideShow = function() {
        return this.each(function() {

            var $this = jQuery(this);
            var $slider = $this.find('.slider');
            var $slides = $slider.children();
            var length = $slides.size();

            var $navigator = $this.find('.navigator');
            var $trigger = $navigator.children();
            var $prev = $trigger.filter('.prev');

            var index = 0;

            slideTo = function (idx) {
                $slides
                    .removeClass('active')
                    .eq(idx)
                    .queue(function(next){
                        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
                        next();
                    });

                index = idx;
            };

            $trigger.click( function () {
                var idx = $slides.filter('.active').index(),
                    prevIdx = idx - 1 < 0 ? length - 1 : index - 1;
                    nextIdx = idx + 1 < length ? index + 1 : 0;
                slideTo(jQuery(this)[0] === $prev[0] ? prevIdx : nextIdx);
            });
        });

    };

})(jQuery);

jQuery('.slideshow').slideShow();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `slideTo` function is in the global scope so it is being changed. To fix it just add `var`

```
var slideTo = function (idx) {
```